# Append attribute to HTML tag in an ASP.NET Content page

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET content page. The HTML tag associated with the content page is declared in the master page. I need to add an attribute to the HTML tag from the content page. My problem is, I do not know how to access this HTML tag from the content page.

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a routine this morning that helps me get a handle on master page controls recursively up the master page hierarchy (if you're using nested master pages). I implemented it as an extension method. Perhaps you'll find it useful:

```
public static TResult FindControlInMasterPages<TResult>(this MasterPage masterPage, string id)
    where TResult : Control
{
    return masterPage == null ? null :
           masterPage.FindControl(id) as TResult ?? FindControlInMasterPages<TResult>(masterPage.Master, id);
}
```

You could apply that like so:

```
this.Master.FindControlInMasterPages<Label>("myLabel").Attributes["attr"] = "value";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always expose it as a property on your Master Page if you have to

```
public Label MyLabel
{
    get { return myLabel; }
}
```

You can then easily access it from your content page:

```
var master = Master as MyAwesomeMasterPage;

if(master != null)
    ((MyAwesomeMasterPage)Master).MyLabel.Attributes["bgcolor"] = "lightblue";
```

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx) will give you more detail, including how to get your Master page property to be strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

I did this once with an ugly hack, as with all hacks it was due to a lack of time to figure out how to do it properly.

I replaced the `<HTML>` tag in the master page with a `<asp:Literal />` control and then exposed that literal control as a property of the master page which I could access from the content page.

It's a horrible way to do it, I'm sure there will be much better answers than this but if you're in a hole it might help.